# Filling for ListPolarPlot

Tags: plotting, options, color

I want to use `Filling` for `ListPolarPlot` in such a way that the points in the list are joined to the origin with a line colored same as in the `Filling -> Axis` of `ListPlot`.

I could do it up to a certain stage, but I couldn't set the color of the lines. Here is what I have done.

Suppose that

```
pl = Table[{k, Sin[k]}, {k, 0, 10}]
```

is the point list. I can connect them to the origin in a tricky way by

```
Show[Table[ListPolarPlot[{{0, 0}, pl[[k]]}, Joined->True], {k,1,Length[pl]}],
     ListPolarPlot[pl]]
```

but I can not set the color of the joining lines as the following code would do.

```
ListPlot[pl, Filling -> Axis]
```

I would be very glad if someone would tell me how to color the lines.

Comment: Have you tried PlotStyle?

Comment: Does adding `PlotStyle -> Directive[Hue[0.67, 0.6, 0.6], Opacity[0.2]]` after `Joined->True` in your code give what you need?

Comment: you can get the specific color directives used in `ListPlot[pl,Filling-Axis]` using `Normal[ListPlot[pl,Filling->Axis][[1]]]`.

Comment: Thank you very much **E.O.** and **kguler**. I found in the examples of *Mathematica*     `PlotStyle->ColorFunction[1,"ColorData"]` but could not find the right color. It seems that I had to change the *Opacity*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
pl = Table[{k, Sin[k]}, {k, 0, 10}];

Show[
    ListPolarPlot[{{0, 0}, #} & /@ pl,PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, Green], Joined -> True], 
    ListPolarPlot[pl]
]
```

Where you can change `Directive[Thin, Green]` to whatever color is appropriate (the specifications in kguler's comment are probably what you are looking for)

Answer (score 2):

You can draw a `Line` from origin to each point

```
Show[
  ListPolarPlot[pl],
  Graphics[{
    Thin,Green,
    Line[{{0,0},#[[2]]{Cos[#[[1]]],Sin[#[[1]]]}}&/@pl]
  }]
]
```

[image: output]

Here's a function that takes a plot as first argument and adds lines from origin styled with following arguments:

```
fill[lpp_,spec___:Blue]:=Show[
  lpp,
  Graphics[{
    Thin,spec,
    Line[{{0,0},#}&/@lpp[[1,3,1]]]
   }]
 ]

lpp=ListPolarPlot[pl];
fill[lpp,Red,Dashed]
```

[image: reddashed]